# Proper handling (capitalization) of the Dutch van in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to set the proper way of handling the Dutch prefixes and so far none of the solutions I have found on Tex.SE so far provide an answer that works in `biblatex`.

The general idea is that Dutch prefixes should be lower case when they are part of the total name and upper case when only the last name is given. In bibliographies, the names should be sorted with the prefixes removed.

This is my current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}} 
    \AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @article{BAN1,
        title = {Gas and Smoke in Interstellar Space},
        author = {Oort, Jan and van de Hulst, Henk},
        journaltitle = {Bulletin of the Astronomical Institutes of the Netherlands},
        volume = 10,
        number = 376,
        year = 1946
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
First citation.: \cites{BAN1}

Second citation: \cites{BAN1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works correct for the first citation and for the bibliography, but not for the second citation where it gives "Oort and van der Hulst instead of "Oort and Van der Hulst"

I tried to fix that using

```
\makeatletter 
     \AtBeginDocument{
         \toggletrue{blx@useprefix} 
         \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeCapital{#1}}} 
     \AtBeginBibliography{ 
         \togglefalse{blx@useprefix} 
         \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{#1}}
\makeatother
```

But then it gives me "Henk Van de Hulst" instead of "Henk van de Hulst" at the first citation. Is there a solution that only capitalizes the prefix when only the last name is given (which is essentially only when the reference is already cited before).

Comment: Not that it matters for the question, but there is a superfluous comma in *`author = {Oort, Jan, and van de Hulst, Henk},`. There should be no comma before the `and`. The correct version would be `author = {Oort, Jan and van de Hulst, Henk},`.

Comment: Good catch, fixed it in the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one wanted to get this completely right one would probably have to check if we are dealing with a Dutch name or with a, say, German name (in German you would only capitalise a "van" or "von" at the beginning of a sentence).

Unfortunately, the conceptually most sensible solution here requires a bit of code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}} 
\AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BAN1,
  title   = {Gas and Smoke in Interstellar Space},
  author  = {Oort, Jan and van de Hulst, Henk},
  journal = {Bulletin of the Astronomical Institutes of the Netherlands},
  volume  = 10,
  number  = 376,
  year    = 1946
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill% just for the example
First citation: \autocite{BAN1}

Second citation: \autocite{BAN1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jan Oort and Henk van de Hulst.//Oort and Van de Hulst]

---

In case you prefer shorter code and like to live dangerously,

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven}[1]{%
  \ifcapital
    {}
    {\def\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital}}%
  #1}

\let\mkbibcompletenamefamily\mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven
```

would work.

Note that this assumes that `\mkbibnameprefix` does not apply any special formatting. The idea is to redefine `\mkbibnameprefix` to capitalise its argument (the "van") if it is not already automatically capitalised by the name format.

Comment: Thank you, both solutions seem to work. Also I was under the impression I needed the `\makeatletter` bit when changing the `useprefix` but it seems I don't?

Comment: @cktai In this case the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is not needed basically because `blx@useprefix` is (at that point anyway) not a command sequence like `\@firstofone`, where you would need the `\makeatletter...\makeatother`. Basically it's the same reason `\csname @firstofone\endcsname` doesn't need `\makeatletter`. (The superfluous `\makeatletter...\makeatother` won't do any harm, but I prefer not using it if it can be avoided.)